# Bindings of UserControl doesn't work properly inside not selected TabItem (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl with such content:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Height="{Binding  Path=FontSize, ElementName=Root, Converter={StaticResource CoefficientConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.65}" 
                 Width="{Binding  Path=FontSize, ElementName=Root, Converter={StaticResource CoefficientConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.65}" 
                 Fill="{Binding Path=Status, ElementName=Root, Converter={StaticResource ServiceStatusConverter}}"
        />
        <!--Other elements-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

(I also tried Binding with `RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl`)

I use this UserControl in many places in my application but I have troubles when try to use it inside `TabItem`

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Service 1" DataContext="{Binding Service1}">
        <ServicePopupStatusUserControl Status="{Binding Status}"></ServicePopupStatusUserControl>
        <!--My Service 1 elements-->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Service 2" DataContext="{Binding Service2}">
        <ServicePopupStatusUserControl Status="{Binding Status}"></ServicePopupStatusUserControl>
        <!--My Service 2 elements-->
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

When page is loaded it loads visual tree only for first (selected) `TabItem`. So when I select second one `UserControl`'s properties have binding errors. Even if `Status` property changed nothing happens. This happens for all TabItem's controls except first one. I can't use ItemSource and DataTemplate because Tabs have different controls inside.

`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Root'`

Comment: Are the properties `FontSize` and `Status` DependencyProperties?

Comment: @GingerNinja yes. `FontSize` is inherited from `UserControl` and `Status` declared and owned by this UserControl. In other parts of application everything works properly. Only not showed TabItem causes errors